# Importing SSL dll into project

Tags: c#, c++, .net, ssl, visual-studio-project

I have a project which I imported from old system.
This code became most problematic

```
PacketGroup = new ArrayList();
Crypto = new GameCrypto(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(STRING_CRYPTO));
KeyExchance = new OpenSSL.Crypto.DH();
KeyExchance.G = RANDOM_INT;
KeyExchance.P = OpenSSL.Core.BigNumber.FromHexString("KEY__KEY_KEY\0");
KeyExchance.GenerateKeys();
NewServerIV = GenerateIV();
NewClientIV = GenerateIV();
```

At first I received the error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenSSL.Native' th
>   rew an exception. ---> System.Exception: Invalid version of libeay32.dll, expect
>   ing 0.9.8a Development, got: 1.0.0 Release

I imported the latest SSL library in the project and got this error (on the line on the line Crypto = new GameCrypto())

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libeay32.dll': The application has failed to start
>   because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the
>   command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
>
> > at PROJECT_NAME.Native.BF_set_key(IntPtr _key, Int32 len, Byte[] data)
> >     at PROJECT_NAME.Main.Blowfish.SetKey(Byte[] data) in PATH\Main\Blowfish.cs:line 85
> >     at PROJECT_NAME.Main.GameCrypto..ctor(Byte[] key) in PATH\Main\Blowfish.cs:line 15
> >     at PROJECT_NAME.Main.GameClient..ctor(Boolean Robot) in PATH\Main\GameClient.cs:line 48

I was able to resolve this problem and I got stuck on this problem (on the line  new OpenSSL.Crypto.DH())

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'OpenSSL.Core.Native' threw an exception. 
>   ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'ssleay32': The operating system cannot run .
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B6)
>
> > at OpenSSL.Core.Native.SSL_library_init()
> >     at OpenSSL.Core.Native..cctor()
> >     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> >     at OpenSSL.Core.Native.DH_new()
> >     at OpenSSL.Crypto.DH..ctor()
> >     at PROJECT_NAME.Main.GameClient..ctor(Boolean Robot) in PATH\Main\GameClient.cs:line 49
> >     System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> >     at PROJECT_NAME.Main.GameWorker.ConnectionHandler(StateObj S) in PATH\Main\GameWorker.cs:line 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a copy of `libeay32.dll`, `libssl32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` in your application directory

1. Add the unmanaged dll as a file or linked file in your project. (right click project -> add -> existing file then either Add or Add as Link).
2. Select the file in the solution explorer. In the properties window set build action to copy always.

> *Don't forget that the unmanaged DLL could itself require other unmanaged DLL's. If you forget to add those as well, you could get the
>   exact same error. You can use dependency walker to help you if you are
>   not sure what the dependencies are.*